# Photon Cloud loosing RPC and updates when changing scenes in Unity

Tags: cross-platform, cloud, unity-game-engine, multiplayer

When I change a scene in Unity it can happen that RPCs/Updates get lost because the new scene is still being loaded / the target is missing. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Pls. provide code to illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, this is a possible solution:

When you load a new scene, all game objects are replaced with new ones. RPCs that PhotonViews of the new scene might arrive before a client loaded everything. If the target is not (yet) known, the RPC is dropped.
This can happen when one client loads fast and another other slow or if they join a running game. In that case, buffered RPCs are received in a chunk.

PhotonNetwork.isMessageQueueRunning is there to pause execution of incoming messages when needed. Set it to false and you can load and setup your scene.
RPCs are silently queued up until you run the message queue again (PhotonNetwork.isMessageQueueRunning = true);